# The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-support-library, actionbardrawertoggle

I am trying to use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and getting the error:

`The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved`

It got no problem importing the v4 type but as I understand, it is deprecated and doesn't function as I want to. Further more, I got no issue with importing other v7 classes like `ActionBar` or `ActionBarActivity` and it happens with the ActionBarDrawerToggle only.

How can this issue (and type) be resolved?

Comment: did you add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'` in dependencies under build.gradle ?

Comment: I am still using Eclipse with the ADT.. is this relevant for Eclipse as well?

Comment: Are you using appcompact - v7 library in to your project as a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some simple steps you need to follow:

1. Go to your project in the navigator, right click on properties.
2. Go to the Java Build Path tab on the left.
3. Go to the libraries tab on top.
4. Click add external jars.
5. Go to your ADT Bundle folder, go to
   sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs.
6. Select the file android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
7. Go to order and export and check the box next to your new jar.
8. Click ok.

Comment: Just to get you even more thumbs up in the future, you can add that you can find the location of the SDK folder when pressing Window->preferences->Android and there you got a text box with the sdk location.

Comment: Do you want to try answering this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577153/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-app-appcompatdelegateimplv14

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) in Android docs (section Adding libraries with resources > Using Eclipse).